Arabxetex and Kurdish in Arabic letters
In the Kurdish language, written in arabic letters there is a special treatment of the arabic letter ە (h). This letter is used in Kurdish to represent the letter e , and exists only in isolated or final position (ە ئە).
The letter h in Kurdish has this final form ﻫ . Arabxetex is not able to produce this letter.
when you write bih the result should be بھ. The result with arabxetex is the single letter b and a single letter h; so it is not combining.
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\fontspec[Mapping=tex-text]{Amiri}
\setmainfont{Amiri}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{german}
\usepackage{arabxetex}
\newfontfamily\kurdishfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.1]{Amiri}

\begin{document}

\begin{kurdish}[novoc]

bih, cih

\end{kurdish}

\end{document}

Result is: ب ھ، ج ھ
